# Strange RSA key

Tags: security, rsa

In a challenge context I get an RSA key with an unusual structure.
The first field is "normally" the modulus, the second should be the "Public exponent" (usually 0x10001).
But in this key the field contains 128 bytes and looks like the "Private exponent"

```
  0 287: SEQUENCE {
  4  13: . SEQUENCE {
  6   9: . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
 17   0: . . NULL
       : . . }
 19 268: . BIT STRING, encapsulates {
 24 263: . . SEQUENCE {
 28 129: . . . INTEGER
       : . . . . *(some data, probably the modulus)*
 02 52 F4
       : . . . . 7D
160 128: . . . INTEGER
       : . . . . *(some data, probably the private exponent)*
       : . . . }
       : . . }
       : . }
```

When I run the algorithm to compute P and Q, the algorithm failed even if I try different "Public exponent" (all "Fermat" numbers between 1 to 100 of (2^2^i+1)).

By the way I suspect this key is not really an RSA key ... but something else.

Did you get already this kind of situation ? 
With an other key format ?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It looks like a SubjectPublicKeyInfo, a very common format for public keys specified in RFC 5280. Nothing strange about that.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. In my humble point of view, the first part contain the modulus and the second the public exponent, only few bits (0x10001 for example). In my case they are 128 bytes. Seems to be unusual ... I'm wrong ?

Comment: Well, a public exponent that is not a small integer is unusual. But the public exponent does not have to be small, and if this is some kind of challenge problem then anything is possible.

Comment: as long as the exponent is coprime to p-1 for every p being a prime factor of N, and e*d = 1 mod phi(N) that is a totally valid rsa key...